Why is cubic function one-one?
The cubic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^3$
is to be proven a one-one function which can be proved by this method
if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then,
$x_1^3=x_2^3$
$x_1^3-x_2^3=0$
$(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2) =0$
now either $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ for cubes of $x_1, x_2$ to be the same
for the set of Real numbers ie. $x_1,x_2$ belonging to $R$ is $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ ever possible ? and how to show that ?
A way I can think of is
since $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2 =0$
it means $x_1^2+x_2^2$ = $-x_1x_2$
now since $x_1=x_2=0$ is not a possibility we will discuss here as we have to show whether the function is one-one or not. We can say that $x_1^2+x_2^2$ will always be $>0$ so for it to be equal to $-x_1x_2, x_1$ and $x_2$ should have different signs.
now again taking this equation $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ and adding and subtracting $x_1x_2$ from LHS
$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2+x_1x_2-x_1x_2=0$
$x_1^2+x_2^2+2x_1x_2-x_1x_2=0$
$(x_1+x_2)^2=x_1x_2$
for this to be true,$x_1$ and $x_2$  should have the same sign thus contradicting our above result.. hence we can say that the condition $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ is not possible for $x_1,x_2$ belonging to the set of real numbers.
Is this explanation correct/sufficient ?
another way I can think for is to conclude, after showing that $x_1$ and $x_2$ should have opposite signs for $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ to be true, that since cubes of numbers with opposite signs aren't equal, the function is not many-one.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You have been on this site long enough to know that you should use mathjax, as @JoséCarlosSantos notes. If you [edit' the question we may be able to help with an answer.

ok, thankyou.. i am doing the edits

What you wrote is hard to read.  More simply, if $a>b$ and $a^3=b^3$ then $0=a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ Now argue that $a^2+ab+b^2>0$ unless $(a,b)=(0,0)$.

Your proof is correct. It's a little wordy, but that's better than not wordy enough.

If $(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2)=0$, then as you implied, either $x_1=x_2$ and we are done, or else $x_1\ne x_2$. Now it is enough to show that for every $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $x_2\ne x_1$, we have $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2\ne 0$. (Note in this way, $x_1$ and $x_2$ cannot both be $0$.)
Let's rewrite our desired result as: For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for every $b\ne x$, we have $x^2+bx+b^2\ne 0$. Assuming the negation, we obtain an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and a $b\ne x$ such that $x^2+bx+b^2=0$. Okay, so let's find what $x$ is. By the quadratic formula, $x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4(1)b^2}}{2(1)}=\frac{-b+\sqrt{-3b^2}}{2}$, but whoops, for $x$ to be real, we need $b=0$. Thus $x=0$, but $b\ne x$, a contradiction.

Thankyou so much :)

Your argument is fine too. This is just an alternative.

thanks.. yours is much sharper and clearer.

I'm not sure. I like the elegance of the same-sign/opposite-sign argument. Different people prefer different proofs. An alternative is always nice to have.

Yes, your proof is sufficient. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ satisfy $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$, then you have shown that both:

$x_1,x_2$ have opposite signs because $-x_1x_2=x_1^2+x_2^2>0$.

$x_1,x_2$ have the same sign because $x_1x_2=(x_1+x_2)^2> 0$.


That's a contradiction, so our assumption is impossible.

Ok, thankyou :)
So can we basically conclude that since 2 different real numbers cannot satisfy $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2=0$ condition, the function (whose domain is $R$) is one one ?

Yes, exactly. You're proof is in two steps. 1. If $x_1,x_2$ are real and nonzero, then $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2\ne 0$. 2. If $x_1^3=x_2^3$ then either $x_1=x_2$ or $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2$.
